# How to use OUTPUT clause with SELECT/INTO statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have the following query

```
SELECT 'Luke' AS [Jedi_names], 'Skywalker' AS [Jedi_surname]
INTO #Jedi
```

which `CREATE` the temporary table `#Jedi` and `INSERT` the data inside it.

I would like to use `OUTPUT` to show the data I am saving inside the table but I can't understand how to use the `OUTPUT` clause without getting an error message

> "Incorrect syntax near 'output'."

In an `INSERT INTO` query I would write the following

```
INSERT INTO #Jedi([Jedi_names],[Jedi_surname])
OUTPUT INSERTED.*
SELECT 'Luke' AS [Jedi_names], 'Skywalker' AS [Jedi_surname]
```

but this just `INSERT` the line if the table has been already created..

**Is it possibile to use the `OUTPUT` clause in the first query?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't use the `output` clause in a `select` statement. It's only applicable in `insert`, `update`, `delete` and `merge`.

An alternative option would be to do it in two parts:
First, create the temporary table with no records:

```
SELECT 'Luke' AS [Jedi_names], 'Skywalker' AS [Jedi_surname]
INTO #Jedi 
WHERE 1=0
```

Then, insert the records into the temporary table using `insert...output...select`:

```
INSERT INTO #Jedi
OUTPUT INSERTED.*
SELECT 'Luke' AS [Jedi_names], 'Skywalker' AS [Jedi_surname]
```

Or simply use `select into` and then `select`:

```
SELECT 'Luke' AS [Jedi_names], 'Skywalker' AS [Jedi_surname]
INTO #Jedi;

SELECT  [Jedi_names], [Jedi_surname]
FROM #Jedi;
```

Answer (score 2):

**Please use like below**

```
CREATE TABLE #Jedi([Jedi_names] VARCHAR(20),[Jedi_surname] VARCHAR(20))

INSERT INTO #Jedi([Jedi_names],[Jedi_surname])
OUTPUT INSERTED.*
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT 'Luke' AS [Jedi_names], 'Skywalker' AS [Jedi_surname]
)K
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Jedi_names  Jedi_surname
Luke    Skywalker
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the syntax you're after:

```
CREATE TABLE #Jedi ([Jedi_forename] varchar(50),
                    [Jedi_surname] varchar(50));

INSERT INTO #Jedi ([Jedi_forename],[Jedi_surname])
OUTPUT Inserted.*
SELECT 'Luke' AS [Jedi_names], 'Skywalker' AS [Jedi_surname]

DROP TABLE #Jedi;
```

You can't use `OUTPUT` and `INTO` in the same statement.

Answer (score -1):

`select into` will avoid the logging. The moment you use the `insert into` then it defeats the purpose.

Comment: The original question is asking how to accomplish this with a `SELECT INTO`, not an `INSERT INTO`; they only use the `INSERT INTO` as an example of how they would accomplish the same query there. Given that, I'm assuming this is intended as a comment on the answers which suggest `INSERT INTO` as a solution?

Comment: Please consider to read the article of SO: how to answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer